# How to clear part of a tkinter Canvas and show something when submit is pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating a simple madlib style game and I've come into a bit of a problem. I cannot get the canvas to clear and show the results.

The following code places an image as the background of a canvas. It then places labels and entry fields in 2 columns for all of the words to be inserted. There is a submit button at the bottom of the page. I can't figure out how to get it clear everything except the background image, so that it can display the story, with the users words inserted. If i place it in the callback(), it clears just the background and keeps everything else. I want the opposite.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

canvas_width = 360
canvas_height = 525
file = r"C:\Users\kraak\Desktop\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.2\borderedpaper.GIF"
master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)

old_img = PhotoImage(file=file)
new_img = old_img.subsample(3, 3)
canvas.create_image(-11, -10, anchor=NW, image=new_img)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, height=1, width=1, anchor=NW)
canvas.create_text(0, 0, text="Test")

e1 = Entry(canvas)
canvas.create_window(250, 60, window=e1, height=15, width=100)
label = Label(text="Enter an adjective.")
label.place(x=40, y=50)
e1.focus_set()

e2 = Entry(canvas)
canvas.create_window(250, 85, window=e2, height=15, width=100)
label = Label(text="Enter a nationality.")
label.place(x=40, y=75)
e2.focus_set()


def callback():
    print("Pizza was invented by a " + (e1.get()) + " " + (e2.get()))

def answer():
    button = Button(text="Submit.", command=callback)
    button.place(x=150, y=460)

answer()
canvas.pack()


mainloop()
```

Comment: Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your problem is with clearing a canvas, you don't need a dozen entry widgets and labels in your example.

Comment: What do you mean by "clear"? Do you want to delete all of the widgets, or simply reset the entry widgets and/or labels to be empty?

Comment: I've shortened my example as requested. I want to delete all of the widgets, except for the background image. After everything is deleted, I want the answers that the user inserted to be printed along with a story.

Answer (score 1):

As Bryan Oakley suggested you can store the id's of the widgets you want to get rid of in a list to make it easier to `destroy()` them all in the `callback()` function. Here's showing the modification to your code that would do that—note the lines with a `# ADDED` comments.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

canvas_width = 360
canvas_height = 525
file = r"C:\Users\kraak\Desktop\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.2\borderedpaper.GIF"
master = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(master, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas_entry_widgets = []  # ADDED

old_img = PhotoImage(file=file)
new_img = old_img.subsample(3, 3)
canvas.create_image(-11, -10, anchor=NW, image=new_img)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, height=1, width=1, anchor=NW)
canvas.create_text(0, 0, text="Test")

e1 = Entry(canvas)
canvas.create_window(250, 60, window=e1, height=15, width=100)
label = Label(text="Enter an adjective.")
label.place(x=40, y=50)
e1.focus_set()
canvas_entry_widgets.append(e1)  # ADDED

e2 = Entry(canvas)
canvas.create_window(250, 85, window=e2, height=15, width=100)
label = Label(text="Enter a nationality.")
label.place(x=40, y=75)
e2.focus_set()
canvas_entry_widgets.append(e2)  # ADDED

def callback():
    print("Pizza was invented by a " + (e1.get()) + " " + (e2.get()))
    # destroy the canvas entry widgets and clear the list  # ADDED
    while canvas_entry_widgets:                            # ADDED
        widget = canvas_entry_widgets.pop()                # ADDED
        widget.destroy()                                   # ADDED

def answer():
    button = Button(text="Submit.", command=callback)
    button.place(x=150, y=460)

answer()
canvas.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every widget has a `destroy` method which can be used to delete the widget. In your callback you can simply call this method for every widget:

```
def callback():
    e1.destroy()
    e2.destroy()
    ...
```

In your specific case, if you want to delete all the labels you will have to give them unique names. Or, to make this even easier, you can store all of your widgets and iterate over the  list.

Comment: I thought about doing the same thing about using a list, but you're not able to destroy a list.

Comment: @MichaelPhillips: But you can iterate through the elements in the list and call each ones `destroy()` method.